# Store a custom object (class in Swift) for access by an Objective-C method

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have created a class in Swift (which I'm learning) that I use to hold certain values as follows:

```
@objc public class Book: NSObject {
    var title: String = ""
    var date: Date = Date()
    var sku: Float = 0
}
```

I would now like to store this class in the equivalent of a property that can be accessed by my Objective-C class.

I tried creating a variable in the View Controller where the class is used as follows:

```
var lastBookViewed = Book()
```

However, when I try to save the object to the property with the followng code, I get an error:

```
//create instance of book
let myBook = Book()
//gather information about book
lastBookViewed = myBook //THROWS COMPILER ERROR 'Use of Unresolved Identifier lastBookViewed
```

Is there a way to do this?

If easier, storing the object to a property in the Objective-C file would work as well but so far I have not been able to get the Objective-C file to recognize the Book class created in Swift although I put @objc before it as recommended.

**Edit**

When I try to create a property or variable for storing the custom swift object in a different Swift class (the View Controller class) in the same Swift file with the following syntax:

```
var lastBookViewed: Book
```

the compiler gives a warning for the VC class "yourVC has no initializers"

Comment: Are you importing the __Project-Name-Swift.h__ file in the objective-c .m file?

Comment: You need to show more code, in context. Where is the code where you are assigning to `lastBookViewed` in relation to the declaration of `lastBookViewed`?  The error is nothing about Objective-C; it simply says that `lastBookViewed` isn't known in the context in which you are trying to use it.

Comment: @Adeel,I imported it to the .m file and am now able to create an ivar or property in the implementation Obj-c file.  (With either, a warning says I must create a method for this property in the .m file.)  How would I set this property or variable from the Swift file?

Comment: @paulw11 You are right the code above has nothing to do with Objective-C.  It's just a first stab at saving a custom object in Swift to be accessed later in Obj-C.  I am merely trying in the code above to create a property in the Swift file for storing the data.  I do this all the time with things like strings and arrays.   But I am unable to do so within the View Controller class for the custom Object.

Comment: There is no difference between using a String or a `Book`, but you need to show the context; Where are you trying to use `myBook` in relation to where it was declared?  The reason you are getting the "no initialisers" is because you have added a property to a class but declared it as optional nor given it a default value; this is covered in the Swift Book

Comment: The need to initialize the class is the answer I was looking for.  I managed to fix the error by adding () after Book.

Comment: I have an additional issue.  This worked in code after lastBook is returned in closure ie {
            answer in
            lastBook = answer
However, it is not working within the closure method before returned.  I am getting error use of unresolved identifier 'lastBook'

Comment: If there is a way to save to a property from within a closure, I have not discovered it, so I refactored the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project’s general settings. Select the proper target for your app. Go to “Build Settings” and switch to “All”, instead of “Basic” which is the default. Here search for the “Packaging” section. Turn on “Defines Module”, by changing “No” to “Yes”.

[image: Screen 1]

> When this is turned on we will now be able to use swift classes inside
>   of objective-c files.

4. Before leaving the “Build Settings” look for “Product Module Name” in the “Packaging” section. This will be important so make sure to take note of and copy the “Product Module Name” exactly.
5. Next go to an objective-c class where you would like to be able to have access to your swift class. In the implementation or .m file of this class import a header like this:

> #import "MyProjectModuleName-Swift.h"

Here the file name of the import must be the exact Project Module Name from the build settings. Any objective-c file where you want access to your swift class should include this import.

6. Now it is worth mentioning one potential issue that may arise when using a swift class. Objective-c cannot read top-level swift classes. So if you go to use a method or variable from your swift class directly it will not be recognized. There are one simple solution to this issue. It’s to make your class `public`

> ```
>  @objc public class myClass
> ```

Comment: I have done muchof this already as I am already going back and forth between Swift and Obj-c.  However, I don't know how to create a property in the swift class for storing data between methods (analagous to property in Obj-c)--or alternatively how to store into an Objective-C property representing a Swift class from the Swift class

Comment: So you’re trying to store data in the swift class from the obj-c method? Pardon my English

Comment: Store object from the swift class directly to a property in the the Objc-Class.  Or Store a custom swift object used in a swfit view controller class in a Swift property and then access that property from the Objective-C class.  Basically, I want to access a custom object in a swift file and class from an Objective C one.